# Questions about Universal application in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, sdk, ios5

I am trying to build an universal application with Xcode 4. However, it seems a little different from past versions.

My project utilizes the View Based Application template. My issue is that I added a `UIViewController` subclass which has one nib file for iPad. How do I create another nib file with the same class targeted instead for iPhone? Also, how do I ensure that the proper nib file is loaded for the proper platform?

EDITED :
here is my code :

```
- (IBAction)BookView {

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        BookViewController *viewController = [[BookViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    } else {

        BookViewController *viewController = [[BookViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create for iPhone:

- New file / ios / cocoa touch / UIViewController subclass
- uncheck Targeted for iPad
- check with XIB

This step will create .m .h and .xib files with same name, for example: CustomView

**Step 2:** Create new XIB for iPad:

- New file / ios / user interface / view
  device family iPad
- for convenience choose the same name with suffix _iPad (for example CustomView_iPad)
- in this xib go to File's Owner, in the inspector tabs choose identity inspector, custom class and choose the same name of class created in step 1.
- Connect IBOutlets.

In your code use something like this:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    CustomView *viewController = [[CustomView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomView" bundle:nil];
} else {
    CustomView *viewController = [[CustomView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomView_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't know why my app crashes when runs on the iPad !! It seems does not load the nib file for iPad !!! see my edited question

Comment: Dont forget connect outlet view. If you did and crash continue, please show me a crash log.

Comment: still crashes !! I connect the outlet but still crash log tells me this 
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException reason: [UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "BookViewController_iPad nib but the view outlet was not set`

Comment: thank you it solved ! I created another nib file and works fine

Answer (score 3):

Name your xib file for iPad **BookViewController~ipad.xib** and the iPhone one **BookViewController~iphone.xib**. Then load the nib file as usual:

```
BookViewController *viewController = [[BookViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

When the app runs on an iPad device, the ~ipad xib will be automatically loaded. If the app runs on an iPhone, the ~iphone xib will be automatically loaded.

Note that **~ipad** and **~iphone** suffixes are case sensitive. If you name it ~iPad for instance, you'll get a runtime exception that the nib file is not found.