# Anyone has a tutorial on how to create Universal app with XCode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

It looks like things changed with XCode 4.2 and I did not see any guide/tutorial on how to create a Universal app with XCode 4.2. Anyone knows one or wrote one?

Note: I'm not talking about how to select your project to be Universal, I'm talking about a Hello World tutorial.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

In case you actually wanted a plain source, compilable as a universal app that writes `Hello World` into the console, depending on the device in use, here comes a tiny snippet for you.

> main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        printf("hello world, from my iPad");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("hello world, from my iPhone or iPod");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Within the build settings of your app, you will have to select:

```
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1,2
```

Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- File / new / new project / ios / application / single view application
- Next
- fill fields and choose "Universal" in Device Family
- Next

Xcode will create a project with 2 initial XIBs with same names and different suffix _iPhone and _iPad.

Enjoy!

Good luck!

Comment: After doing that, how do I proceed? Let's say I would like to display a table view. Do I have to create TWO tableviewcontrollers, one for iPhone and one for iPad, ie, tableViewControllerForiPhone and tableViewControllerForiPad? When I run the app on the iPhone, how will it know the tableViewControllerForiPhone is the one it should show? Do I have to put a conditional statement like if (iPhone) push tableViewControllerForiPhone; ?

Comment: But what if I want to have multiple view application?

Comment: When you create universal application, appdelegate implement first call with condition device. See another question about universal application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232099/questions-about-universal-application-in-xcode-4/8232742#8232742

Comment: While we creating single view application it creates with storyboard which feasible for iOS 5.0.... i ned to make it for lesser version

Answer (score 0):

Look for any `Hello World` iPhone OR iPad app. Make sure you set the project to Universal.

- iPhone: http://www.tuaw.com/2009/04/27/iphone-dev-101-the-hello-world-app/
- iPad: http://hijinksinc.com/2010/07/23/entry-level-xcode-hello-world-for-ipad/

Answer (score 0):

Try :

Head First iPhone and iPad Development, 2nd Edition
A Learner's Guide to Creating Objective-C Applications for the iPhone and iPad
By Dan Pilone, Tracey Pilone

They have a great section on Universal Apps :)

Comment: I din't find anything pertaining to universal app in the book that you referred it was `Head First iPhone Development by Dan Pilone & Tracey Pilone`. Please recheck and reply.