# Universal App Example

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-universal-app

I would like to make a simple app with a UITableView and a Details View. I've already done that before. The only difference now is that I would like it to be an universal app that is organized like this :

- For iPhone : a UINavigationController with 2 levels. My TableView Controller and then a UIViewController to show the details
- For iPad : an UISplitViewController for both the TableView and Details view controller.

I don't know where to start. Could someone point me on a good tutorial for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try googling, and searching stackoverflow?

Comment: For example, this question is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232933/anyone-has-a-tutorial-on-how-to-create-universal-app-with-xcode-4-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a code example at this location : https://github.com/kwylez/Universal-iOS-App-Template